# Display issue with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, display

I updated from 10.04 to 12.04 and am seeing the following screen which is very disturbing. Not sure what the issue is. Is this a known issue?

[image: Display issue in Ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the terminal (CTRL+ALT+F1) and then remove the configuration file ~/.config/dconf/user like this :

(this action will remove your gnome 3 settings)

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start
```

Hope this helps!